# Binding AngularJS with JavaScript Plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openseadragon

I'm trying to bind AngularJS with JavaScript Plugin - OpenSeaDragon, because I have to do annotations on OpenSeaDragon's image and I tried something like this

```
angular.element(document.body).scope().$on('addAnnotation', function(e, data){    
    self._viewer.viewport.fitBounds(new OpenSeadragon.Rect(data)) 
});
```

And inside the controller:

```
$scope.addAnnotation= function (data) { 
   $scope.$root.$emit('addAnnotation', data);
}
```

And in my view:

```
ng-click="addAnnotation(data)"
```

but I am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you put the plunkr link. The usage seems to be wrong

Comment: Actually it would be very difficult to put in in plunker since it is chunk from web application, but i found a solution thanks to @ronapelbaum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get `angular.element(document.body).scope()` which is `undefined`. 
In order to get the `scope` of an element, this element should have a scope.
Try using it on a DOM element that binds to a controller.

Comment: So for example it should be `angular.element(document.getElementById("openSeaDragon"))` which is instance of Open Sea Dragon

Comment: something like that, yes.

Comment: I used 

`angular.element(document.getElementById("openSeaDragon"))`

and it seems working but I had to remove `$root` from `$scope.$root.$emit('addAnnotation', data);`

and setTimeout to 100ms because it looks like this code worked before ng-view has loaded.